# Given two sequences $a_n \to a$, $b_n \to b$, does $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n^{b_n} = a^b$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Question is in title. I (think) I need this to be true to prove a problem for a homework. I'm having trouble proving this with the epsilon definition of limits in a style similar to that of the proofs of the other limit laws. Any help?

Comment: I think you need some assumption on $a,b$ for this to make sense, say $0 \leq a,b < \infty$, so that you don't run into complex numbers or division by zero.  What happens when $a=0$ or $b=0$?

Comment: Can we assume that $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and that one of $a$ and $b$ is non-zero?

Comment: This is just *continuity* of the exponentiation operation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Limits_of_rational_exponents or http://books.google.it/books?id=5YhXVE9slLsC&lpg=PA259&hl=it&pg=PA278#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: If you've been told to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition, then so be it. But I would prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n\log a_n = b\log a$ and then exponentiate. This uses the continuity of exponentiation (and of the logarithm, to get $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log a_n =a$ in the first place), as well as the limit of the product of two sequences which presumably is available to you.